# Does external drag&drop or copy/paste work in IntelliJ IC Linux?

Tags: linux, drag-and-drop, intellij-idea, copy-paste

Information on [IntelliJ's Blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/07/drag-drop-between-intellij-idea-and-explorerfinder/) says that drag&drop in Linux is supported as it uses the same JAVA API as Windows version. However, although I've enabled this feature in the app's properties, I cannon drag a file on Linux desktop (or from any Explorer window) and drop it in some /res folder. I cannon copy a file on desktop and paste it in any /res folder as well.

Anyone knows the way to enable this feature or make it work?

PS. The same version is installed on Windows 7 x64 and drag&drop (c/p as well) works flawlessly. I use Ubuntu 10.04 x64, but I think it's the same in all distros.
PPS. I've tested both IC and IU versions and neither supports drag&drop or c/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the blog, this feature is supported on **Windows** and on **Mac**, there is no word about Linux.

If you want it to work on Linux, vote for [IDEA-42872](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-42872).

Comment: Windows and Linux uses the same API so whatever is supported in Windows, it is supported in Linux as well. At least, this is what the developers say.

Comment: So it could be Java bug after all, write once, test everywhere.